# Meaning of the phrase "you are on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I have come across this usage in the 18th episode of the 10th season of *Friends*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/aW-m5hzhTGg). It's at 2 minutes and 41 seconds.

> Gate attendant #2: I'm sorry, you cannot go any further without a
> boarding pass.
>
> Ross: No, no, no, but...
>
> Phoebe: (screaming) RACHEL!!
>
> (Rachel comes back to the gate.)
>
> Rachel: Oh my God... What.. What are you guys doing here?
>
> Phoebe: Okay, **you're on**.

No definition in this [dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you%27re+on!) and others, it seems, doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having watched the clip, it seems to me that "You're on" has nothing to do with the preceding dialogue. They have tried to stop Rachel from taking the flight because Ross wants to make a declaration of love to her, and Phoebe tells him "You're on" meaning "This is your moment to speak."

Comment: And did he....?

Comment: Yes, that's how I know what she meant by it!

Comment: And did he get what he hoped for?

Comment: I must be the only person on the face of the globe who has never managed to sit through an episode of 'Friends'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know - I've never watched it either. I deduced the answer from watching the next bit of dialogue!

Answer (score 2):

"You're on" means it is your turn to talk. I guess it is said when one has to speak in a microphone. You're on means the microphone is on and you will be heard (so you have to be careful what you say).